# How to determine if GPU or PSU is causing shut downs?

Tags: power-supply, gpu, shutdown

I've been having consistent (15-20 minutes while under load) PC shutdowns that occurred spontaneously a few days ago. These shutdowns are like someone pulled the plug on my pc and then booted it up again - no BSOD. I've gone through all the traditional steps to determine what is causing them, but I am still at a loss. The only hunch I have is that it involves power usage by my GPU or my PSU - tough to distinguish which because of how much power the GPU uses. Is there a way to tell (besides switching out the parts) which is causing the shutdowns? OCCT GPU and Power tests cause shut down - temps are fine though. CPU test does not cause crash. I think this means its power related, however the total wattage never goes above 550w.

Any metric in OCCT or HWInfo that I could monitor?

Below is my system and the things I have tried to diagnosis or fix the issue:

```
- HWINFO Monitoring temperature (all averages and max temps are in
  normal range when shutting off- nothing above 85c)
- Checked fans (all working and at good RPMs)
- Removed dust and airflow obstructions
- Temp throttling not even triggering before crash
- Updated CPU, GPU drivers, as well as Windows
- Ran Windows Memory Tool, System File Checker, and antivirus scan
- Reviewed Event Viewer but the logs are not informative and just    indicate a shutdown occurred
- Disabled fast boot
- Checked SSDs and are all healthy
- Moved plug from power bar and tried different outlets.
- Removed extra SSD but OCCT GPU benchmark still causes crash
- Reseated GPU, Ram, and SSD
- Cleared CMOS
```

System:

```
Windows 11 Home
Intel Core i5-12600KF
MSI PRO Z690-A DDR4(MS-7D25)
GIGABYTE RTX 3080 GAMING OC LHR (GV-N3080GAMING OC-10GD_A)
32GB DDR4-3200
PSU 850W Coolmaster fully module
```

Comment: Get the manufacturer’s Hardware Diagnostic App and test all hardware.

Comment: You could try limiting the power draw of your videocard through software. This can usually be done with software provided by the manufacturer or some 3rd party software. MSI Afterburner for example can set a power limit. This might help in determining the problem. Usually, a GPU wont cause a reset like that, it would just overheat and start throttling.

Comment: @Silbee Yah, this seems to be the issue. When I undervolt the GPU (and the watt consumption stays low) it passes he stability test; however, any sustained gameplay still causes it to shutdown. Gonna look into buying another PSU and testing it out - one other thing I noticed is that my GPU was using a single daisy chained cable. That might have hurt the PSU, cable, or pin connector.

Comment: I just looked up coolermaster PSU's and noticed some have advanced features like switching between single and multi 12V rails. You wouldnt happen to have one of those where you might have switched it to multi rail and potentially overload it ? Daisy chaining wouldnt typically hurt if you have a single 12V rail. Anyway, its a tough one to test unless you actually get your hands on another PSU. Good luck !